# Capture a newline with shift+enter ng-submit

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am writing a chat application in AngularJs.  I have an input form for submitting a message using ng-submit.  On pressing enter the form submits, which I want.  How with the ng-submit directive can I capture a new line on a shift+enter.

```
<form id="sendMessageForm" name="sendMessageForm" class="form-inline" ng-submit="homeCtrl.sendMessage()">
        <input ng-model="homeCtrl.msg" id="inputChat" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your Message"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The sendMessage() function just grabs the message submitted from the form and packages it in an MQTT payload.  The problem is that upon enter or any other combination of a key+enter the form submits.

Comment: catch the shift key with ngKeyDown on the input and stop propagation.

Comment: for multi line you use **<text-area>** instead of **<input type="text">**